# TI sensortag CC2650 with Kura example issue

Tags: osgi, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, texas-instruments, kura

I'm having a problem with tisensor tag kura example.
I am using Raspberry Pi 3 with TI sensortag CC2650. (connected via bluetooth).
`TI sensortag's hardware revision is 1.3.2` and `software revision is 1.2.1`
When I enable all sensors , and I want to read values from them, I got only Temperature and accelerometer values. Looks like that sensortag resets after that and then starts from beggining.

I used BlueZ tool also, and I can read values from any sensor.
I can read with Kura also, but I cann't read them all together. I tried with mobile app to read from sensortag, and it works good.
I am using Kura 2.1.
Does anybody have idea what could go wrong? ( Collegue of mine is getting all values good, with same hardware and software setup. I tried his deployment package, but I had same result.)
Could it be something with Raspberry Pi bluetooth module?

I am using **org.eclipse.kura.example.ble.tisensortag** example.

Kura web panel setup :

http://prntscr.com/ek868g

Terminal log :

http://prntscr.com/ek86hp

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with firmware on CC2650 TI sensortag. This firmware changed something on handles and characteristics. It was not full compatible.

Comment: How did you solve this - was it stock firmware and you updated it?

Comment: Yes, but we don't have necesarry equipment(development board, jtag, etc.), so we sent them tag, and they upgrede it.

Comment: i have the same issue.Can you tell me to whom did you send the tag to upgrade

Comment: My company send it to our partners who are working more with embedded devices and have necessary equipement. You can do it by yourself on two ways :
- In first case, you will need http://www.ti.com/tool/CC-DEVPACK-DEBUG
- In second case, (I don't know which programming language you use), but it can be that register addresses aren't maped good, maybe you are reading from wrong registers.